# Maven command to go back to previous day snapshot

Tags: maven, maven-3

I am using following spring neo4j snapshot dependency in my project,

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
```

Today morning, after mvn install, i got the latest snapshot from the repository. However, i would like to use the previous snapshot instead of the latest one.

Is there any mvn command to do this? 
I found out commands to work offline or to get latest one but didn't find one to go back to particular snapshot.

Kindly let me know if there is any such command.

Thanks,
Abdul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your maven settings are pointing to http://repo.springsource.org, you can always search for a particular version like [spring-data-neo4j-2.1](http://repo.springsource.org/webapp/search/artifact?13&q=spring-data-neo4j-2.1).

Once you click on a version like 2.1.0.RC2 you can view **Show In Tree** then see a sample of the maven pom settings:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.RC2</version>
</dependency>
```

Or you can page through to find the particular snapshot version you are looking for like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.BUILD-20120817.105144-37</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2553485/1297972):

```
...
<dependency>
<groupId>groupid</groupId>
<artifactId>artifact-id</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-20090610.041042-5</version>
</dependency>
...
```