# Maven uses different timestamps when building snapshot artifacts in a large project

Tags: maven, timestamp, snapshot

We have a large maven 3 project with around 250 modules. All modules have version 1.0-SNAPSHOT and modules tree has single parent module with the same version as a tree root.
Project is built with Bamboo nightly and artifacts are installed to a Nexus repository using command "mvn clean install".

It happens that part of modules are built with one timestamp while the rest with the other, something like:
module1-1.0-20121127.150154-7.jar
module100-1.0-20121127.150527-7.jar

In another project I was trying to set dependency to artifacts of this project using specific version of a snapshot dependency (as discussed in this question [Maven specific version of a snapshot dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368625/maven-specific-version-of-a-snapshot-dependency)) but failed to build due to the problem described above.

Does anyone know why maven would use different timestamps and how to fix that?

Comment: mvn install will not deploy artifacts to a Nexus. mvn deploy will do so. As far as i know the timestamp is created by Nexus at the time it receives the artifacts which usually is at a different time.

Comment: You are right, we are doing mvn deploy after mvn clean install (to avoid partial deploy of the project if any of modules fail to build). I reviewed more artifacts and can confirm this behavior is consistent - each artifact does get it's own timestamp. My initial observation was probably due to several modules built in a single minute which made them have the same timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

[MNG-6754](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6754) was finally fixed in 3.8.2.

Comment: Bug was closed as WONT_FIX