# locking snapshot versions when depending on multi-module project

Tags: maven

I have a multi-module project (B) that depends on various modules of another multi-module project (A).  Each module of (B) might depend on different parts of (A), but they should all use the same version of (A).  Current that version is specified as a property in the parent pom of (B).

I would like be able to lock the version used to a specific build (x.y.z-ts-buildnum) from a single command while keeping the version of (B) to use listed only once.

In parent:

```
    <dep.version>4.1.0-SNAPSHOT</dep.version>
```

In a module:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>B-foo</artifactId>
  <version>${dep.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I tried:

- [versions:lock-snapshots](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/lock-snapshots-mojo.html) but that does not seem to lock versions set by properties
- [versions:update-properties](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/update-properties-mojo.html) which is for updating property versions but not locking snapshots
- Writing a script around resolving the latests snapshot of A's pom from the local repository, but that does not work because [each module has it's own timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13589893/maven-uses-different-timestamps-when-building-snapshot-artifacts-in-a-large-proj).  I could write a script to look at every module, but that's getting close to the amount of work a maven plugin would do.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to define the dependencies to your module-A in your parent of the module-b like this:

```xml
<properties>
  <module-a.version>6.5.0-12-SNAPSHOT</module-b.version>
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.example</groupId>
      <artifactId>A-foo</artifactId>
      <version>${module-a.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.example</groupId>
      <artifactId>A-bar</artifactId>
      <version>${module-a.version}</version>
    </dependency>
   ...
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Within your modules you now only need to write:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>A-bar</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

which will give you the possibility to change the version of all modules only within a single place. At the root of your module-A.

Comment: Doesn't this still leaave `module-a.version` as a property that can not be automatically locked by the maven-versions-plugin?