# Maven how to download snapshot for a given date

Tags: maven

I've got a webapp that produces JSON output as an API. Let's call this Search. This modules is built by Jenkins and published to repo after a successful build as a snapshot version.

SearchClient is another module that invokes various end-points in the Search module above. Day to day there are a lot of queries generated from various logs and reference data. Let's call this search.csv.

What I want to be able to do is the ability to download the Search artifact from yesterday and run against this new search.csv and get a baseline. Then download another Search artifact from the lastest build today and run it against this search.csv and compare the output.

So is there a way to download a particular snapshot for a given date? eg. yesterday date and today date? Do I have to require two pom.xml for this dependency? or a property passed in from command line somehow?

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards
Tin

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368625/maven-specific-version-of-a-snapshot-dependency .. Please check this question . I think this will have what you are looking for ..

Comment: Sorry I had been to that link prior to asking the question. Essentially SearchClient needs to find the last 2 successful builds of Search. Could be a few days apart if the Search build happens to fail for a few days in a row. On a given date, if the Search published snapshots a few times, only the last one will be used for that date. SearchClient then downloads the relevant artifact and deploys it locally and run against each of the 2 versions to compare results. So I am still struggling to find out how to find the right version to download from SearchClient pom.xml. Regards